# Filtering Fields with Custom User Model -- Django

Tags: django

Very new to Django.

I created a custom user model as below. I also created a page for the users to update their details. I want the two user 'groups' to use the same page 'account.html' to update their details. But if the user is an 'Employee' I want to display additional fields.

Simply put, I'm trying to achieve the following logic:
If users group = 'Client' then display fields A & B to update
If users group = 'Employee' then display fields A, B, C & D update

Any help much appreciated

Models.py

```
group_types = [('Client', 'Client'), ('Employee','Employee')]

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    groups = models.CharField(choices=group_types, default="client", max_length=60)
    company_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='company name', max_length=30)
```

account.html

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Account Details</h1>
  <p> Email Address </p>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus value={{account_form.initial.email}}>
  <br>
  <p> Username </p>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="inputUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus value={{account_form.initial.username}}>
  <br>
  <p> Company Name </p>
  <input type="text" name="company_name" id="inputCompany_Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" required autofocus value={{account_form.initial.company_name}}>
```

Comment: Can you add your current view and form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`modelform_factory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory) to generate a form dynamically, you can pass different fields depending on the user

```
FIELDS = {
    'Client': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    'Employee': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
}

def view(request):
    form_class = modelform_factory(Account, fields=FIELDS.get(request.user.groups))
    form = form_class(instance=request.user)
    ...
```